# How do ISPs calculate bandwidth?

Tags: bandwidth, isp, measurement

I mean, is 100 GB per month 100 * 1000^3 bytes or 100 * 1024^3 bytes? Wondering if they use the decimal definition like HDD manufacturers or the binary definition.  I do know that there's technically Gibibyte (GiB) for binary but it's not commonly used (at least I think so).

Answer (score 1):

Anecdotally, ISPs and service providers in general tend to state numbers using whichever math looks best to customers and simultaneously requires the least from the provider. As each ISP is unique and has developed their own special brand of mathematics, I will avoid giving you specific numbers and instead encourage you to query your provider on the very specific equations that they use. Get it in writing, and then, if you have the time and inclination, measure your usage against their records of your usage and compare the two to make sure the quotes numbers that you received are really what you're being measured with.

What do you get when you cross an ISP with a demononic hell spawn that belches vile abominations and defilment? "Error: Table already exists. Try using a different database name."

Answer (score 0):

I find most providers operate on this method:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burstable_billing

Check out the first section on 95th percentile.  This is for concurrent bandwidth.

If you are talking about residential ISP it's pretty straightforward to get bandwidth utilization from a switch.

Also this might be of use to you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth_cap